# How do I set up PHPMailer correctly?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a problem with a code line: $mail = new **PHPMailer**;. Word with bold font causes error. The error message is

> Undefined type 'phpmailer\PHPMailer'.intelephense(1009)

I don't know how to fix it and what to do despite checking a lot of instructions. I have installed PHPMailer via Composer.

There are code fragments on HTML and PHP:

```
<form name="form" action="mail.php" method="post" id="form_message" style="align-self: center; width: 97%; height: 360px;">
    <p> <div class="titles">Ваше имя*</div> <input class="input" name="name" type="text" style="width: 99%;"/> </p>
     
    <p> <div class="titles">Электронная почта*</div> <input class="input" name="email" type="text" style="width: 99%;"/> </p>
     
    <p> <div class="titles">Тема сообщения</div> <input class="input" name="subjects" type="text" style="width: 99%;"/> </p>
     
    <p> <div class="titles">Текст сообщения:</div><textarea name="message" cols="22" rows="5" style="width: 99%;"></textarea></p>
    <p><input id="submit" value="Отправить" type="submit" /></p>
  </form>



<?php

use phpmailer\PHPMailer;
use FFI\Exception;

if($_POST){

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'phpmailer/Exception.php';
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/SMTP.php';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subjects = $_POST['subjects'];

$mail = new **PHPMailer**;

// Настройки
$mail->Host = 'smtp.server.ru';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Username = 'xxx'; // логин от вашей почты
$mail->Password = 'xxx'; // пароль от почтового ящика
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = '465';
$mail->From = 'xxx'; // адрес почты, с которой идет отправка
$mail->FromName = 'Админ'; // имя отправителя
$mail->addAddress('xxx');

// Письмо
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Body = "Имя: {$_POST['name']}<br> E-mail: {$_POST['email']}<br> Тема сообщения: {$_POST['subjects']}<br> Сообщение: " . nl2br($_POST['message']);
$mail->AltBody = "Имя: {$_POST['name']}\r\n E-mail: {$_POST['email']}\r\n Тема сообщения: {$_POST['subjects']}\r\n Сообщение: {$_POST['message']}";
//  $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

  if( $mail->send() ){
    $answer = '1';
  }else{
    $answer = '0';
    echo 'Письмо не может быть отправлено. ';
    echo 'Ошибка: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  }
  die( $answer );
}
?>
```

Comment: To create a new class instance, you need to initiate it correctly: `new PHPMailer()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing three things wrong.

Firstly, you're not using the correct fully-qualified class name for the PHPMailer class or the local alias (the `use` statement), so it won't match loaded classes when you try to create an instance. It should be this:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
```

Secondly, given that you're using composer, you don't need to load the classes manually as composer does it for you. I'd guess you probably added these lines because of the first problem, but found it didn't help. Delete these lines:

```
require 'phpmailer/Exception.php';
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/SMTP.php';
```

also, if you're really loading it from composer, those paths are wrong. These files should be in the `vendor` folder.

Finally, you could have saved yourself the effort of writing this question and waiting for answers by simply [reading the documentation which tells you how to load PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#installation--loading).

Comment: I fixed things that you pointed on, but problem is still present. And I have read a lot of examples and guides before asking for help. I really don't know why it does not take PHPMailer as new definition. It seems like it does not take any definition.

Comment: Please show your changes in the question so we can see what might be happening.